# Android Market - Number of Installs

Tags: android

What if somebody installs one app and from the market and then removes it and then installs it again, then will the number of installs still increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your Market "Publish"-Dashboard, you'll see two figures for your app: Number of overall downloads and number of current installs. The Market App shows the first figure. So   installing an app, removing it, and installing it again will not artificially increase the number of downloads.